# Kubernetes: ./hack/local-up-cluster.sh requires authentication

Tags: cluster-computing, kubernetes

I've updated my local [`kubernetes`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes) from `master` (Dec 2016) to `v1.5.3`
I used `hack/local-up-cluster.sh` to start my local cluster:

```
sudo KUBE_ENABLE_CLUSTER_DNS=true \
    SERVICE_CLUSTER_IP_RANGE="10.100.0.0/16" \
    API_HOST_IP=0.0.0.0 \
    hack/local-up-cluster.sh
```

After the update I have this error:

```
Creating kube-system namespace
Cluster "local" set.
Context "local" set.
Switched to context "local".
Please enter Username: admin
Please enter Password: ********
Please enter Username: admin
Please enter Password: ********
Please enter Username: admin
Please enter Password: ********
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "namespace.yaml": namespaces "kube-system" already exists
Please enter Username: admin
Please enter Password: ********
Please enter Username: admin
Please enter Password: ********
Please enter Username: admin
Please enter Password: ********
deployment "kube-dns" created
Please enter Username:
```

How can I fix it?

Full log:

```
0.0 hack/local-up-cluster.sh
[sudo] password for dmitry: 
make: Entering directory '/opt/kubernetes'
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/kubernetes'
can't load package: package .: no buildable Go source files in /opt/kubernetes
can't load package: package .: no buildable Go source files in /opt/kubernetes
can't load package: package .: no buildable Go source files in /opt/kubernetes
can't load package: package .: no buildable Go source files in /opt/kubernetes
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/kubernetes'
+++ [0227 19:34:34] Building the toolchain targets:
    k8s.io/kubernetes/hack/cmd/teststale
    k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/go-bindata
+++ [0227 19:34:34] Generating bindata:
    test/e2e/framework/gobindata_util.go
+++ [0227 19:34:35] Building go targets for linux/amd64:
    cmd/kubectl
    cmd/hyperkube
make: Leaving directory '/opt/kubernetes'
API SERVER insecure port is free, proceeding...
API SERVER secure port is free, proceeding...
Detected host and ready to start services.  Doing some housekeeping first...
Using GO_OUT /opt/kubernetes/_output/local/bin/linux/amd64
Starting services now!
Starting etcd
etcd --advertise-client-urls http://127.0.0.1:2379 --data-dir /tmp/tmp.FhAud4KuG4 --listen-client-urls http://127.0.0.1:2379 --debug > "/dev/null" 2>/dev/null
Waiting for etcd to come up.
+++ [0227 19:34:38] On try 2, etcd: : http://127.0.0.1:2379
{"action":"set","node":{"key":"/_test","value":"","modifiedIndex":4,"createdIndex":4}}
Waiting for apiserver to come up
+++ [0227 19:34:39] On try 2, apiserver: : {
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "5",
  "gitVersion": "v1.5.3",
  "gitCommit": "029c3a408176b55c30846f0faedf56aae5992e9b",
  "gitTreeState": "clean",
  "buildDate": "2017-02-27T11:05:22Z",
  "goVersion": "go1.7.4",
  "compiler": "gc",
  "platform": "linux/amd64"
}
Creating kube-system namespace
Cluster "local" set.
Context "local" set.
Switched to context "local".
Please enter Username: admin
Please enter Password: ********
Please enter Username: admin
Please enter Password: ********
Please enter Username: admin
Please enter Password: ********
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "namespace.yaml": namespaces "kube-system" already exists
Please enter Username: admin
Please enter Password: ********
Please enter Username: admin
Please enter Password: ********
Please enter Username: admin
Please enter Password: ********
deployment "kube-dns" created
Please enter Username:
```

`kubectl config view`:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /var/run/kubernetes/apiserver.crt
    server: https://localhost:6443
  name: local
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: local
    user: ""
  name: local
current-context: local
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

`kubectl config get-contexts local`:

```
CURRENT   NAME      CLUSTER   AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
*         local     local
```

Comment: Could you please post the relevant parts of the output of `kubectl config view` at the moment the prompt shows up?

Comment: Is there actually a CA certificate in `/var/run/kubernetes/apiserver.crt`? Is your API server started with the `--ca-cert-file` flag?

Comment: The only command I run is `hack/local-up-cluster.sh`. It worked before the update. I didn't install any certificates (but the file exists).

Comment: It seems like TLS support is fairly new, check this commit: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/20d1818d78746247785f327b89028a35f5ca6caa

Comment: I didn't find a way to disable this type of authentication in `hack/local-up-cluster.sh`. Also I don't run any other commands. This `hack/local-up-cluster.sh` setups and runs cluster itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `local` context is configured without a user, but your cluster seems to be configured to use a CA. If your cluster is using a CA you either need a user with a valid certificate, signed by the aforementioned CA, or a valid user token in order to communicate over TLS.

The script you mentioned [gives some hints](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.5/hack/local-up-cluster.sh#L635-L643) about the way you should configure your client after it completes, try to follow these steps:

```
cluster/kubectl.sh config set-credentials myself --username=admin --password=admin
cluster/kubectl.sh config set-context local --cluster=local --user=myself
cluster/kubectl.sh config use-context local
```

Another option is to change your local configuration in a way that you communicate over the *insecure* port, which defaults to 8080. You can achieve that with following command:

```
kubectl config set-cluster local --server=http://localhost:8080
```

References:

- [Authentication: X509](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#x509-client-certs)
- [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/)
- [local-up-cluster.sh](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.5/hack/local-up-cluster.sh)

Comment: Thank you. I had to run `cluster/kubectl.sh` before `hack/local-up-cluster.sh`